# How to know mail send or not send in laravel and which recipient is not getting it?

Tags: laravel

Hi I am using the bellow function, can you please guide me how can I use Mail::failures(); in it

```
Mail::send('emails.caregiversetprimary', $templateArray, function($message)use($email)
{
    $message->to($email, 'username')->subject('my subject');
});


Mail::failures(); < ====== this gives me black array as I have used wrong email
```

I am using laravel 4.1

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

You can know which recipients the email has been sent to but no which recipients have received it.

**details**
You need a better understanding of how mail servers work. From a Laravel point of view, there is no way (or at least not a simple one*) of knowing which recipients got the email. Its a matter of how mail protocol works. You may know which recipients the message has been sent to but no which recipients actually got it.

With `Mail::failures()` you get a list of recipients to which Laravel tried to send the email but it failed on actually sending it. But again, if it has been sent there is no straightforward way to known if the mail reached their inbox or no.

*If you happend to use Mailgun, Mandrill or any other 3rd party software then you are not dealing with a mail server 'per se' but with an API service. May be you could check the mail service provider documentation to research if they perform any kind of delivery tracking that you can programatically check.

Comment: ok can i check that mail send or not like general php mail function if($mail == true) { }  ..something like this because in above function it gives me nothing